# Void to Boolean Processing

Tags: boolean, processing, void

I'm trying to check if the .save method is execute but I'm getting "Cannot convert from void to boolean" error. How could I check it? Also the `img.save()` doesn't work in a web applet, any clue why it doesn't work?

```
PImage img  = get (180, 0, 620, 400);

if( img.save("img/111,jpg") )
{
fill(0, 255, 0);
}
else
{
 fill(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is assuming true or false will be returned by `img.save()` function. Therefore you need to check what the `img.save()` is returning. If that is a method than it cannot return any value back once it has been executed meaning you cannot compare it...

Put the method call in `try/catch` if you expect that the method could fail...

Comment: Sorry for my ignorace, but how do I put the method call in try/catch?

Comment: `Try { img.save(); } catch (e){ //error debugging code } ...` It is always good practice to call any method or function that might possible cause an error...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I have a new question. Do you know how I could send the PImage img = get(); data result to a PHP script so I could upload it to a the server?

Answer (score 0):

One thing at a time:

1. You set fill, but don't draw anything afterwards(at least in the code posted) *
2. By default some functionalities might not work without [signing the applet](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Sign_an_Applet).
3. You can't use PImage's save() method to do an upload for you. Here's a quote from the documentation:

> It is not possible to use save() while running the program in a web
>   browser.

You will need to use a serverside script to pass data to which in turn will save the image to the serser. Have a look at [Philho's upload sketch](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~philho/+junk/Processing/files/head:/ImageUpload/). Notice that he is passing data to a php script which handles writing the file on the server.

*although not as important, you can try this in the Processing IDE/locally to see the colour change:

```
if( img.save("img/111.jpg") )
{
fill(0, 255, 0);
}
else
{
 fill(255, 0, 0);
}
rect(0,0,width,height);
```